# RAID5 failure but drives are OK. 2 of 5 drives "failed" simultaneously. How to restore? Windows 11, Intel RST

Tags: windows-update, raid-5, testdisk, intel-rst, data-loss-prevention

I have two drives in my RST RAID5 drive registered as "unknown" and thus the RAID5 array with 5 drives reports as "failed".

Windows 11 Pro 23H2, Intel RST (Intel Optane Memory and Storage Management), ASUS TUF X299 MARK 2.

The failure on both drives seems to have happened after a Windows Update (KB5031451), as the event log states:

```
Event ID:      442

Device settings for SCSI\Disk&Ven_ATA&Prod_WDC_WD102PURZ-85\4&a61befe&0&000400 were not migrated from previous OS installation due to partial or ambiguous device match.

Last Device Instance Id: SCSI\Disk&Ven_HPT&Prod_DISK_0_0&Rev_4.00\5&10508b60&0&000000
Class Guid: {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Location Path: 
Migration Rank: 0xF000FC000000F120
Present: false
Status: 0xC0000719
```

There is no way to roll back the update, and the RAID seems to be broken. However, both the "unknown" drives show up as available for spares. IMHO it indicates that they are OK, but fell out of the RAID during the Windows update?

Whatever the reason, I need to get the RAID back up, and hope to use `testdisk`. Any recommendations/advice? Can I mark the drive as OK one by one and re-introduce them to the RAID?

I am currently making mirrors of the failed drives and trying to do all the required housework before attempting to recover the RAID.

PS - The two "failed" drives are of the same vendor/size, but with different firmware versions.

Comment: RAID 5 (striped across all drives) - when 2 drives fail, you need to restore from your backups.

Comment: That's the common wisdom, but it does not apply to my situation.. The drives are not failed. the raid is compromised due to windows update. hence; I need to get the 2 drives  back in the raid without data loss. The disk.inf seems to have been modified by the windows update procedure, with subsequent raid failure

Comment: You may wish to change the Post Title in this case so as not to mislead.

Comment: The Service pack that installed when raid broke: KB5031451

Comment: Did you use software RAID?

Comment: Intel RST (now Intel Optane Memory and Storage Management) yes, onboard raid on tuf x299

Comment: If you lost two drives in a RAID 5 configuration there is no recovering from that situation

Answer (score 1):

Since KB5031451 was only recently released as [Windows 11 **Insider Preview** Build 22635.2483 (KB5031451) to the **Beta Channel**](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/kb5031451-windows-11-insider-beta-build-22635-2483-23h2-oct-13.18825/), it likely had some bugs.

- Disconnect from the network, to avoid possibility of getting that update again.
- [Restore](https://superuser.com/questions/394860/recover-data-from-raid-0-disk-images) from the last set of disk images,
- [Forbid](https://www.minitool.com/news/how-to-block-specific-updates-on-windows-10-11.html) that bad update.
- Then reconnect to the network.

While it is good to volunteer as a *beta* tester, one should be prepared for occasional issues. Even on the release channel, there are [sometimes updates with bugs](https://www.manageengine.com/patch-management/resources/microsoft-known-issues.html).

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else who may end up in this situation; do not despair, do not panic, but **do** take your time to get all the scalpels and tools ready before you start your surgery. If you jot down all the details you can get hold off, research the potential pitfalls and how to avoid them, there is a good chance you can get your data back safely.

I did. How?

To recap: two of the 5 drives in my raid5 fell out of the raid during/after a W11 preview update. As [DrMoishe Pippik](https://superuser.com/users/401553/drmoishe-pippik)
pointed out; signing up for preview updates comes with risks. I have now turned off all beta updates, just to feel safer. I still don't know for sure if the update derailed the drives, but it's just not worth it for me.

Now, the raid 5:  Knowing that the drives were all physically ok, I ran any possible raid recovery software I could think of. Testdisk, Stellar Data Recovery, Disk drill, File Scavenger and Klennet (former ZAR) came back with correct block size and sequence and returned intelligble directories and filenames, but with mixed results in recovering the files; they stayed garbled (even with photo repair add-ons etc). HOWEVER: [ReclaiMe](https://www.reclaime.com/default.aspx), with a little help of their free add-on raid recovery, recreated the drive and let me restore all the images. I'm still in the process of restoring, but so far all image files (dng, cr2, cr3, arw, jpegs) are opening up with no problem or damages.

All this to say; All is not necessarily lost, literally, when 2 drives drop out of a raid 5. It all depends on whether there is physical damage, if you can recreate with the correct block size and sequence (preferably on clones or disk images, and never ever write to or modify the drives before you have at least a full, functioning, up-to-date backup.

And there are lots of good tools out there, spanning from totally free to the overly expensive. As every case is a little bit different, I'd have to say I was quite impressed with how some of the recovery softwares performed. In my situation, the ReclaiMe did the trick for a modest sum, saving me a career full of data.

In closing: Thank you, all helpers, for all the help! To all the nay-sayers who spelled doom; get out of my way - you're slowing me down ;)

**ps:** *The event viewer is a treasure trove: Chances are you'll find the cause of your misery there, and the lead-up as well as changes. Save filtered reports from within the hour before and after, and you have lots of actionable intelligence*

Comment: "_ReclaiMe did the trick for a modest sum, saving me a career full of data_" - I'm delighted you seem to be on track to get your data back... but please heed the warnings, and implement a proper backup procedure for what sounds like quite important data!

Comment: Thanks, Attie, I agree with the backup idea. I have triple backup, whereas 2 of them are offsite. My raid failure was a perfect storm: it hit while I was reconstructing / consolidating backups from another incident (overzealous customs removed cmos cell during transport, compromising server). Backup indeed! And backup of backup! Redundancy is peace of mind